# How can I delete an item from a Databound windows phone application?

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7

Starting with the stock Databound application, I replace the xaml on the MainPage

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

with this:

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
<TextBlock Name="ItemName" Margin="10,10,0,0" Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Grid.Column="0" />
<Button Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click" BorderThickness="0" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
</StackPanel>
```

In Button_Click(), I’d like to remove that item from Items. I know the syntax would be something like App.ViewModel.Items.Remove(something)
but I’m missing what that something is. How can I ensure the correct item is removed based on the value of LineOne that is displayed?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about doing this. The best way is with an ICommand. But you also need to add a CommandButton class to hold the reference and the parameter.

If you want a quick workaround though, then the sender object in the button click event should be the button you clicked, and its DataContext property should be the list item. A nasty hack but a lot less work than going down the ICommand path if you are just messing around learning the tools.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  App.ViewModel.Items.Remove((ItemViewModel)((Button)sender).DataContext);
}
```

Comment: Windows Phone doesn't currently have an implementation of ICommand. To get a similar effect, you'll want to look into one of the MVVM frameworks like Caliburn or MVVM Light. These allow you to send the list item as a "message" or parameter to a method that removes the item from the list. But that's about 10 steps from the beginner stage. :)

Comment: Chris, I'm getting the error: "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'tmp_FavoritesUpdate.ItemViewModel'"

Comment: The list items in this example are of type `ItemViewModel` rather than `ListItem`. I'm playing with some different casting options to make sure we're getting the right item.

Comment: @JoshEarl ICommand is supported, I use it. You just need to roll your own button subclass that has the properties.

Comment: @Freakishly I updated the code in my answer to code that worked on the databound template project here.

Comment: Chris, according to the Microsoft employee in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/windowsphone7series/thread/5C9D186E-4D3A-436B-8DC8-08E012923606), ICommand is not supported in WP7. Maybe you're using the Mango release?

Comment: @JoshEarl Don't know what to tell you, but I've had a published app since October that uses System.Windows.Input.ICommand and a custom CommandButton. No Mango involved. Perhaps we have a different idea of what ICommand is? We are diluting this question though.